# how to authenticate in Rogglevision

Tags: r, google-api, google-oauth, google-developers-console

In order to use Rooglevision in R I did

```
library(RoogleVision)
creds = fromJSON('client_secret.json')
options("googleAuthR.client_id" = creds$installed$client_id)
options("googleAuthR.client_secret" = creds$installed$client_secret)
options("googleAuthR.scopes.selected" = c("https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"))
googleAuthR::gar_auth()
```

However it gives me this error:

```
400. That’s an error.

Error: redirect_uri_mismatch

The redirect URI in the request, http://localhost:1410/, does not match the ones authorized for the OAuth client. 
Please update the authorized redirect URIs.
```

I've left the redirect URI in credential pane of google api web client blank, as it states it's for 'use with requests from a web server'. I'm requesting from R so not sure what to fill in here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redirect uri must exactly match the location of the website you are sending it from.   Basically where you want it to handle the response from the authentication server.

If you are not using a web serer then you should be using a type other credentials and not web credentials.